# Statistical saturation attack on block ciphers

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher

I was wondering if anyone around here could give me some explanation on this type of attacks. Pretty much the only thing that I could find is [this](http://www.uclouvain.be/crypto/services/download/publications.pdf.b348a292669d7d09.5353415f50726573656e742e706466.pdf)

What I really need is basic explanation of the attack itself with a small example if possible such as any basic block cipher that you could come up with, with 3-4 rounds. This is for my personal understanding so any input is more than welcome

Comment: Could you indicate what you don't understand from the paper you've linked to? Note: just trying to improve the question here.

Comment: Well, I understand that the attack is possible because of a weakness in the diffusion layer in some block ciphers but I am not quite sure of the purpose of the required plain text. Also, you won't know the output of each round as the keys are unknown so how do you actually recover the keys?